# How to build 1D Convolutional Neural Network in keras python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am solving a classification problem using CNN. I have data.csv file (15000 samples/rows & 271 columns), where 1st column is a class label(total 4 classes) and other 270 columns are features(6 different signals of length 45 concatenated i.e 6X45=270).

**Problem:** 
I want to provide single sample of length 270 as vector(6 X 45, all 6 signals have different meaning) but I am getting error in dimensions when reshaped a single sample to (6 rows, 45 colums) in convolution.
My CNN model:

```
X, y = load_data()   
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
num_classes = 4

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 6, 45).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 6, 45).astype('float32') 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(6, 45)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5 ))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

How to reshape my data that CNN treats every single sample as 6 signals of 45 length and convolve with kernal of window 5.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: As default, keras uses channels last, so I suggest using `input_shape=(45,6)` if length=45 and signals=6.  For that you may need `np.swapaxes(X_train,1,2)` to invert the dimensions without changing the order of the data.

Comment: Original Error: "Negative dimesnsion size caused by subtracting 5 from 2 for max_pooling1d_2/MaxPool with input shapes: [?,2,1,6]" same error  after inverting the dimensions `np.swapaxes(X_train,1,2)`

Comment: Exactly my comment then, and the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reshape your data like

`X_train.reshape(num_of_examples, num_of_features, num_of_signals)`

and change your `input_shape` in model to `(45, 6)`. See the example code below,

```
X = np.random.randn(4000,270)
y = np.ones((4000,1))
y[0:999] = 2
y[1000:1999] = 3
y[2000:2999] = 0

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
num_classes = 4

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 45, 6).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 45, 6).astype('float32') 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(45, 6)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5 ))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Caution: make sure your original data is sequences in the form (45,6), otherwise create X_train as `(-1,6,45)` and call `np.swapaxes(X_train,1,2)`

Comment: @DanielMöller in this setup, I envision for each sample there is a 2d array where the rows are the various signals and the columns are the elements of those signals. Stated another way, each row is a time series. is that correct? In this example 6 rows and 45 columns. And given that, is it accuate to consider a kernel as an array that is [filter  length=5] rows and 45 columns and it moves down the 6x45 matrix for the convolution?

Comment: @B_Miner  In Keras (except for convolutional layers where you have the option of using `channels_first`), the channels or the features always go last, and the middle dimension is for time steps or length. So, in a shape like (samples, 45, 6) you have 6 different signals/features measured in 45 different moments.

Answer (score 1):

The `input_shape` parameter specifies the shape of each input "batch".  For your example it has the form: `(steps, channels)`  `steps` being number of observations on each channel, `channels` being the number of signals.  When actually running

```
model.fit(X,Y)
```

The `X` will be in the form `(batch, steps, channels)`, each batch being each observation of your data. Use 3 dimensional `numpy` dataframes for this.

`numpy.vstack()` may come in handy